Specifying parameters mentioned in Datasheet in MATLAB Simulink
I am a first year Electrical Engineering undergrad. I am trying to simulate a circuit in MATLAB Simulink. I have a 2SC5200 transistor in the circuit for which I need to specify parameters from datasheet. I am confused about what to enter in the "Output admittance", "Current Ib for voltage V_BE" field and in "reverse current transfer ratio,BR" field (higlighted in red box) as I couldn't able to find these parameters in the Datasheet of the transistor. How to find and specify these parameters? Also I have mentioned the h_fe paramaters and V_BE (highlighted in yellow box) as per the "h_fe(2)" given in the datasheet (took the typical value of h_fe as 60). Is it correct to mention it ? I am attaching pictures for reference. Thank you.

Main Parameters of 2SC5200 transistor found in the datasheet:

Link to the datasheet of the transistor: https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/2SC5200_datasheet_en_20160107.pdf?did=20668&prodName=2SC5200
